# GridView Update command Not updating Database but does not throw an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

GridView row updating event won't update database but its not throwing an error either, it just does nothing

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server 2014, I wrote code to execute what I want on another form in my project so I decided to copy and paste the existing code onto the new page but I started getting errors which was already surprising as its a copy and the original works fine but I fixed those but the update button still isn't changing the database

```
protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    // Finding the controls from Gridview for the row which is going to update 
    Label id =(Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_ID") as Label;
    TextBox Plate = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Plate") as TextBox;
    TextBox Make = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Make") as TextBox;
    TextBox Model = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Model") as TextBox;
    TextBox Description = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Description") as TextBox;
    TextBox Route = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Route") as TextBox;

    string ID = id.Text;
    string plate = Plate.Text;
    string make = Make.Text;
    string model = Model.Text;
    string Desc = Description.Text;
    string route = Route.Text;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = SHIREDOCKS\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = JerichoCarPark; Integrated Security = True");

    con.Open();

    // updating the record  
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("VehicleUpdate", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VehicleID", ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VehiclePlateNo", plate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VehicleMake", make);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VehicleModel", model);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VehicleDescription", Desc);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("JTARoute",route);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    // Setting the EditIndex property to -1 to cancel the Edit mode in Gridview  
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

    // Call ShowData method for displaying updated data  
    ShowData();
}

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="Yellow" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="5px" CellPadding="6" Font-Names="Kozuka Gothic Pro B" style="z-index: 3; left: 322px; top: 112px; position: absolute; height: 470px; width: 1167px" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView2_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="GridView2_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView2_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView2_RowUpdating">
             <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#99CCFF" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:Button ID="btn_Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" BackColor="#3366FF"  Font-Names="Century Gothic" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Medium"  BorderStyle="Solid" CausesValidation="True" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                             </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>

                            <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" BackColor="#3366FF"  Font-Names="Century Gothic" ForeColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>
                            <br></br>
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" BackColor="#3366FF"  Font-Names="Century Gothic" ForeColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                            <br></br>
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" BackColor="#3366FF"  Font-Names="Century Gothic" ForeColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VehicleUpdate]
    @VehicleID VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @VehiclePlateNo VARCHAR(6) = '',
    @VehicleMake VARCHAR(20) = '',
    @VehicleModel VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @VehicleDescription VARCHAR(225) = '',
    @JTARoute VARCHAR(20) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Vehicles
    SET [VehiclePlateNo] = (@VehiclePlateNo),
        [VehicleMake] = (@VehicleMake),
        [VehicleModel] = (@VehicleModel),
        [VehicleDescription] = (@VehicleDescription),
        [JTARoute] = (@JTARoute)
    WHERE [VehicleID] = @VehicleID
END
```

I expected it to update the database like the original page does but it just re loads and shows the un updated table

Comment: I don't see any exception handling, are you sure you are not swallowing errors? Can you tell if the stored procedure runs? Have you run SQL Profiler to observe what happens in the database?

Comment: Can you do some profiling? An easy way is to add `Console.WriteLine` in places (this will print values into your console), add break points, or try throw exceptions in your code. Let us know where you get to with that.

Comment: im not going to lie im new and I don't really understand sql profiler yet but in my breakpoint it says the value for the textboxes are the same unchanged text but when I 'count' the executenonquery its returns greater than 0. so that means something was changed right?